# Log into webpage without submit

Tags: html, excel, dom, vba

Im trying to log into a web, which is basically a user/password form:

[image]

Also the source code:

[image]

My problem is: using Excel vba i have tried to use the form.submit method but this just refresh the page, so i tried to locate and click the button but aparently i am doing something wrong:

```
Sheets("Hoja1").Cells.Clear
Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate "https://smap.komatsu.co.jp/cgi-bin/webdriver"
'Wait until IE is done loading page
Do While ie.READYSTATE <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
DoEvents
Loop
'show text of HTML document returned
Set html = ie.Document
ie.Document.forms("IDPASS").elements("user_id").Value = "inter62535"
ie.Document.forms("IDPASS").elements("paswrd").Value = "******"
Set boton = ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("TD")
boton(5).Click
```

Is there something aditional i have to reference in order to fire the click event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to inform that i managed to solve the problem by calling the java function:

`Set html = ie.Document
ie.Document.forms("IDPASS").elements("user_id").Value = "inter62535"
ie.Document.forms("IDPASS").elements("paswrd").Value = "******"
ie.Document.parentWindow.execScript "errmsg(document.IDPASS);`

That is since the action of submitting forms was returning false (see the first image)

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try submitting the form directly.

```
with ie.Document.forms("IDPASS")
    .elements("user_id").Value = "inter62535"
    .elements("paswrd").Value = "******"
    .submit
end with
```

Comment: I tried that, it only refreshes the page and cleans the password, i guess submit its not the function that does the log function.

Comment: It seems that you will have to delve deeper and find out what `errmsg()` does.